# Can I get back the cards I lose in the Card Queen Quest?

Tags: final-fantasy-8

I always wondered if I take part in card queen quests can I get my card back>

Take for example the Irvine card:

- Lose Sacred to Queen.
- Win irivine from Flo in the windmill of FH.
- Can I get my Sacred back afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Queen_of_Cards), you can win back cards lost to the Card Queen by battling her son:

> Once the new card has been created, the player must locate the Queen's son in order to win back the card they lost. The Queen's son is located in a house on the outskirts of Dollet (he is the little boy who keeps placing a bone in the artist's painting).